# How does capturing unique_ptr by reference in lambda work correctly?

Tags: c++, c++17, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

In one function I have this:

```
void main() {
  auto poller = std::make_unique<Poller>();
  auto polling_func = [&poller] {
    poller->Poll();
  };
  // assume foo signature is correct for passing
  if (condition) foo(std::move(polling_func));
  else foo(std::move(some_other_func));
  // other things happen
  poller->DoSomethingElse(); // this is why I cannot move poller completely inside the lamda
  return;
}
```

Later, `polling_func` is called in `foo`. This program both compiles and runs correctly. However I am feeling really icky about capturing the `unique_ptr` in lamda by reference. How does this work behind the scene and should I do this at all?

Using `C++17` with `GCC 9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I am feeling really icky about capturing the `unique_ptr` in lamda by reference.

There is nothing wrong with that as long as you make sure that the captured object lives past the life of the lambda.

That applies to any object that is captured by reference by a lambda.

Comment: I see. So what is exactly captured in that lamda? A reference to the pointer itself?

Comment: @resnet, the lambda captures a reference to the `unique_ptr` object, not the pointer underlying the `unique_ptr`.